# Set rotating threhsold on AccessLogValve

Tags: tomcat, logging, log4j, access-log, tomcat-valve

Can we set up size based log rotation on AccessLogValve rather day/time based ?

Additional question :

I am looking for some thing like max back up index flag in RollingFileAppender of log4j.

Should we monitor externally to delete the access_log* files ?

Comment: As per http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve, No